# ng-repeat weird behaviour bringing back removed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

think of my app like a todo list, the user can add and remove item. And as usual practice, I use ng-repeat in for my items list. No issue in the backend. but this has happened :

I push something using unshift (instead of append using push I prepend), and remove using remove(). I removed an item and when I insert the new 1, the ng-repeat seem bringing back the deleted element back to the list. This is so different with using jquery. Need helps from Angularjs Guru, thanks!

Comment: Can you make a simple plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: When you say "remove using remove()" what do you mean? Arrays don't have a remove method. Maybe you could build off of this, which seems to be working, and make it resemble your project a bit more: http://jsfiddle.net/p9hmT/

Comment: I know what is my problem. I couldn't use remove() because even it's gone but the object is still there.. look like I need to remove the object.

Comment: Ah, you mean you're using the jQuery `remove()` method to remove from the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the item from the array rather than removing an element from the DOM. Splice is kind of a weird function, but basically to remove a single item at index `i`, you'll do something like this:

```
$context.splice(i, 1);
```

Typically, with frameworks such as AngularJS, you should avoid doing any DOM manipulation; let the data drive the view.